# ASP.NET Ajax Controls that still provide some level of functionality with javascript turned off

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

I am looking for some ASP.NET Ajax Controls (similar to [those by Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx)) that, unlike those [those by Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx), still provide some level of functionality when the end user has javascript disabled. Does anybody know of any products like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to do that in my open source library of components: http://nucleo.codeplex.com, but I haven't heard of any third-party specific controls.  Adding that type of functionality really adds to the amount of time it takes to develop AJAX components, especially with the level of complexity of most control frameworks.